# android - how to switch screens with an intent if the original class is not an Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Usually if I want to switch screens, I do something like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
CurrActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

but I am in a situation where I would like to do this from a regular class. Actually it is an abstract class.  It is named PurchaseObserver and its part of the Android billing setup.

Is it possible to do a change of screens from this class?  Something similar to the intent code I posted above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate the class, pass a `Context` in the constructor and use that to start an Activity using `startActivity(Intent)`

Comment: that is a good point, but I think it is not possible in this case because the Android OS calls that method.